# Add JSON Schema properties (title, description) to C# class properties using Json.NET JsonSchemaGenerator

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I'm working on generating a HTML form dynamically from a class in C#. My current approach is to generate a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) from the C# class using the [JsonSchemaGenerator](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchemaGenerator.htm) included in Json.NET on the server side and then render the form from this JSON Schema on the client side.

I want to be able to add JSON Schema properties such as a [title or description](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor98) to the properties of the C# class, but can't find any simple way to get JsonSchemaGenerator to include these in the generated schema.

I can add these JSON Schema properties to the class itself using one of the C# attributes [JsonObjectAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm), [JsonArrayAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonArrayAttribute.htm), or [JsonDictionaryAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonDictionaryAttribute.htm), but using the [JsonProperty](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute for the properties, I can only change whether the property is required or not.

In essence, what I want is to generate this JSON Schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "MyString": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Title for my string"
        }
    }
}
```

from this class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Should I write a custom [JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) or add in the schema properties manually? Is Json.NET not the right tool for the job? Is JSON Schema the wrong format for this in the first place? Or is there just some fancy function of JsonSchemaGenerator that I've missed?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution on how to do this with Json.NET? I also need to specify property descriptions...

Comment: I modified Json.NET to do what I wanted, but the changes are not merged into the main project. They can be found here, though: https://github.com/kimsey0/Newtonsoft.Json/commits/master

Comment: It got rejected because it contains multiple features. Maybe we should create a fork per feature?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I made the patch for work, we moved away from JsonSchemaGenerator and I haven't found time to clean up the pull requests. Feel free to fork the project twice, apply my patches and submit a pull request for each one, though - I'd be happy to see them merged in.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonSchemaGenerator` considers all objects of a type to have the same schema ("type" in generic sense, not `Type` class). It's not designed to support individual schemas for properties. It considers `Title` and `Description` attributes of a type, not of a property (this is why it looks only for `JsonContainerAttribute` and its descendants). Therefore, even if you manage to use `JsonConverter` as a workaround (to generate "types"), it would essentially be a hack.

If I understand correctly, the way Json.NET treats `Title` and `Description` is wrong. I recommend [submitting a feature request/bug report](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues).

P.S. I just looked at the code, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks. I would agree with you, except that the Required property of the JsonProperty attribute allows me to change the schema for each property somewhat. But I will sure submit a feature request if I don't find a better answer.